# jQuery Validate: Clear Individual / Specific Field Error with Select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

There's some kind of bug with connecting jQuery Validate to Select2: it doesn't automatically clear errors on typing, like it does with regular controls.

Therefore, I'm forced to do a manual on-change Clear on this field only (but not any others).

```
$('#approverReviewers').on('change', function (e) {
    //...
});
```

But how to do it? I don't want to do a Form-Reset, it's not the whole form.

And I don't like manual CSS removal: it's dirty and doesn't address the underlying internal Validation status, I assume? There are 2 separate parts (the field itself and its label) and I don't want to do it.

```
$(element).parent().removeClass('error');
$(element).remove();
```

Isn't there a better way?

Comment: Also see:  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery-validate%5D+select2

Comment: Either write a jQuery event handler that programmatically validates this `select` (see duplicate), or modify the `highlight` and `unhighlight` functions to conditionally check the select.  The former is easier to implement.

Comment: Yeah it worked for me. That .valid() call for the on-change did the trick. thanks